# Create a String out of a String array so that is readable

Tags: java, arrays, string

I got a code that looks like this:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < encodeCharString.length; i++) {
    strBuilder.append(encodeCharString[i]);
}
String outputString = strBuilder.toString();
f = outputString.length();
if(...){
    String[] outStringCopy = outputString.split("");
    outputString = "";
    String[] outStrArr = new String[outStringCopy.length];
    while(f>0){
        outStrArr[outStringCopy.length-f-1] = outStringCopy[f-1];
        f--;
    }
    strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < outStrArr.length; i++) {
        strBuilder.append(outStrArr[i]);
    }
    outputString = strBuilder.toString();
}
textArea.setText(outputString);
```

If the `if` isn't executed the output is correct.
If the `if` is executed the programm stops (no text in textArea).
When I go in Debugging mode it says that the `outputString` hasn't got any "", but it has a value Array with the correct text.

Comment: I can't tell from this code whether `encodeCharString` is a an array of characters, but if it is you can just do `String outputString = new String(encodeCharString)` instead of using the `Stringbuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info on error output, I can say that at least, you should have an `indexoutofboundsexception` here:

```
while(f>=0){
    outStrArr[outStringCopy.length-f-1] = outStringCopy[f-1];
    f--;
}
```

When f is 0, you try to access to outStringCopy[-1] which throws a runtime exception.

In fact, in the first iteration f is equals to `outputString` length which is the same than `outStrArr` length.
So `outStrArr[outStringCopy.length-f-1]` leads to `outStrArr[-1]`, you should get an error on the very first iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your while loop here:

```
    while(f>=0){
        outStrArr[outStringCopy.length-f] = outStringCopy[f-1];
        f--;
    }
```

Try to replace this with the following code:

```
 while(f>0){
      outStrArr[outStringCopy.length-f] = outStringCopy[f-1];
      f--;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is an attempt to reverse the String. So we need `outStrArr[outStringCopy.length-f] = outStringCopy[f-1];`

Comment: I thought so too, but based on the names of his variables i thought otherwise. I will update my answer just in case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reverse the String, then you can use [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29).

```
if(...){
    strBuilder = new StringBuilder(outputString).reverse();
    outputString = strBuilder.toString();
}
textArea.setText(outputString);
```